# Hibernate - difference update using save() method vs. update using update() method

Tags: java, hibernate, object, persistence

I have an simple Hibernate Project where I update an existing Object using the save method.

So the following code works for me.

```
sessionObj.beginTransaction();
MyObject myObj = sessionObj.get(MyObject.class, objID);
myObj.setPropertyA("new value");
sessionObj.save(myObj);
sessionObj.getTransaction().commit();
```

I obtain the Object with the ID objID via get() method, change a value, mark it as persistent using save() method and commit the transaction. I observed that Hibernate generates an UPDATE Statement in this case.

So if I can make an UPDATE this way using save() method whats the difference make an update using the update() method?

Like

```
MyObject myObj = sessionObj.get(MyObject.class, objID);
myObj.setPropertyA("new value");
sessionObj.update(myObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

SAVE (method)

> The save method is an “original” Hibernate method that does not
>   conform to the JPA specification.
>
> Its purpose is basically the same as persist, but it has different
>   implementation details. The documentation for this method strictly
>   states that it persists the instance, “first assigning a generated
>   identifier”. The method is guaranteed to return the Serializable value
>   of this identifier.

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("John");
Long id = (Long) session.save(person);
```

> The effect of saving an already persisted instance is the same as with
>   persist. Difference comes when you try to save a detached instance:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("John");
Long id1 = (Long) session.save(person);

session.evict(person);
Long id2 = (Long) session.save(person);
```

> The id2 variable will differ from id1. The call of save on a detached
>   instance creates a new persistent instance and assigns it a new
>   identifier, which results in a duplicate record in a database upon
>   committing or flushing.

UPDATE (method)

> As with persist and save, the update method is an “original” Hibernate
>   method that was present long before the merge method was added. Its
>   semantics differs in several key points:
>
> it acts upon passed object (its return type is void); the update
>   method transitions the passed object from detached to persistent
>   state; this method throws an exception if you pass it a transient
>   entity. In the following example we save the object, then evict
>   (detach) it from the context, then change its name and call update.
>   Notice that we don’t put the result of the update operation in a
>   separate variable, because the update takes place on the person object
>   itself. Basically we’re reattaching the existing entity instance to
>   the persistence context — something the JPA specification does not
>   allow us to do.

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("John");
session.save(person);
session.evict(person);

person.setName("Mary");
session.update(person);
```

> Trying to call update on a transient instance will result in an
>   exception. The following will not work:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("John");
session.update(person); // PersistenceException!
```

For more information please folow this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate)